# Replace NA values with characters based on unique value in other column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

**Situation:**

I have a large dataset with a column for country code (`country`) and next to it a column with the country name (`country_name`). I need help replacing the NA values for the two observations in the `country` column with NA in the corresponding `country_name` column:

1. EL
2. UK

EL should have Greece in the country_name column.
UK should have United Kingdom in the country_name column.

I am in the process of tidying the dataset, so the solution would be used in my cleaning for the dataset as a whole. Obviously, I would like to keep the remaining columns as is given that the `country` column has the correct information in the `country_name` column.

**Reproducible Data:**

```
    structure(list(country = c("EL", "EL", "EL", "EL", "EL", "UK", 
"UK", "UK", "UK", "UK"), country_name = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), type = c("Conventional thermal", 
"Conventional thermal", "Conventional thermal", "Nuclear", "Nuclear", 
"Conventional thermal", "Conventional thermal", "Conventional thermal", 
"Nuclear", "Nuclear")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What have you tried and where have you found issues? Also the post is tagged with both `dplyr` and `data.table`. Do you prefer either package? Would base R solution work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large data sets I would recommend working with a mapping file:

```
country_map <- tibble(country = c("EL", "UK"), 
                      country_name2 = c("Greece", "United Kingdom"))
```

The mapping file contains all countries and the corresponding names.
You can then join the mapping file to your data and use `coalesce` to update country names.

```
data %>% left_join(country_map, by = "country") %>%
  mutate(country_name = coalesce(country_name, country_name2)) %>%
  select(-country_name2)
```